# Insert into view of two tables?

Tags: mysql, view

I've worked a lot w. MySQL, but not with views. What I want to do is conceptually simple. Have two tables, create a view that combines them, and insert/update/delete to the view like a table. Something like:

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `baseuser` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `uname` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    `pwd` varchar(55) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `facultydet` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `baseuser_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `department` varchar(55) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE ALGORITHM = MERGE
 VIEW `facultyuser`
 AS SELECT `baseuser`.`id` AS `id`, `uname`, `pwd`, `department` 
 FROM `baseuser`, `facultydet` 
 WHERE `facultydet`.`baseuser_id` = `baseuser`.`id`;
```

The above creates the view 'facultyuser', which I can update, but I can't insert or delete from the 'facultyuser' view. Is there any way to do this directly with a view like this? I've tried different variations on the VIEW and TABLE defs, looked at the mysql docs, but obviously I'm missing something. Any advice appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the docs [18.4.3 Updatable and Insertable Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/view-updatability.html):

> With respect to insertability (being updatable with INSERT
>   statements), an updatable view is insertable if it also satisfies
>   these additional requirements for the view columns:
>
> There must be no duplicate view column names.
>
> The view must contain all columns in the base table that do not have a
>   default value.
>
> The view columns must be simple column references. They must not be
>   expressions or composite expressions

Additionally, you can't modify more than one table in a join'd view, so you're essentially out of luck with this approach.

> It is sometimes possible for a multiple-table view to be updatable,
>   assuming that it can be processed with the MERGE algorithm. For this
>   to work, the view must use an inner join (not an outer join or a
>   UNION). Also, **only a single table in the view definition can be
>   updated**

Comment: Wow, that's really unfortunate, but clearly the correct answer. Thanks.